# Does the server always receive AJAX requests in the same order they are sent?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a web page that sends information via AJAX to a server. I need to make sure the server handles the requests in correct order. Is it possible that the server might receive the requests in different order from what they are sent? The web page makes sure that the requests are sent in correct order, but time between requests can be very short. The page doesn't receive data back from the server so the responses don't need to be in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on your server and the server load. Normaly the request, if they don't require much processor time, they should be handled in the correct order.

To be absolutly sure, you may implement a sending queue. The second request, waits for the first to be completed, and so on. This requires of course much more implementation effort.

Answer (score 5):

Since every AJAX request runs in its own connection, there is no guarantee whatsoever that  *asynchronous* requests will arrive in the same order they were sent.

If you want to be sure they arrive in the same order they are sent, use synchronous requests.
Another possibility is to pack requests together in one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a guarantee that your requests are handled in the exact order that you issued them. If the order is important, you probably should either bundle the requests up as one or wait for each to return before you issue the next.

Answer (score 1):

Each AJAX request from the browser could travel a different network path to the server. So if the browser makes asynchronous requests in the order 1,2,3,4,5 they might show up in that order when doing casual testing, but at some point they may arrive in an order something like 1,2,5,3,4 when something changes on the network. If the order of messages received by the server matters, you will need to create a message queue.